# POST Status Code: 401 Unauthorized While Clicking a Button to save the changes through Cypress Automation

Tags: cypress

I am trying to Click on a Button that submits the input changes during the automation in Cypress. While performing manual test it is working fine.

I also noticed that in the browser network tab it is showing 401 status code and also POST url which is wrong and you can see in the screenshot that url is different.
[image]

Comment: This could be due to your tests being dependent on the previous. Are your tests starting from a clean state each test (ie. visiting app beforeEach test)?

Comment: Yes before each test there are user login test which includes visit to app.

Comment: Interesting. In my previous company, we had an app where cypress tests would be logged out after clicking a sort column. I think I had to save some cookies to keep the user logged in before initiating the clicks to the sort.

Comment: How did you save your cookies? can you share that code here?

Comment: I'm don't quite remember the exact implementation, but I do know it was either setting the localStorage or setting the cookie before invoking the action that redirect the user to the login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I got help from Filip Hric. 401 usually means that you are not authenticated, which can mean that you get logged out while running your test. this may be caused by the test design - maybe you split your flow into multiple it() blocks? Cypress clears all the data between tests, so that may cause you to be logged out. it would explain why you are getting 401, but going through the flow manually works fine.